# C# combine strings representing hour+minute combinations

Tags: c#

I'm working with timestamps in the form of [(h13m30){h4m30}]
Right now i've gotten to the point where I have "13.30" and "4.30" in string format. I now need to combine these strings in such a way that 4.30 is added to 13.30, resulting in a string with value "18.00". However, this adding needs to comply with the 24h clock (e.g 23.00 + 4.00 would need to result in 03.00, not 27.00).

I can use DateTime.Add to add the 4.30 to 13.30, but i'm not sure how to convert the string "13.30" to a DateTime format. Could you help me out?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`TimeSpan` struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("13.30", "h\\.mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("4.30", "h\\.mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
TimeSpan tsResult = ts1 + ts2;
string result = tsResult.ToString("hh\\.mm");  // 18.00
```

Comment: Perfect, helped me alot!